# Sharing a large dataframe with multiprocessing.pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a function which I want to compute in parallel using multiprocessing. The function takes an argument, but also loads subsets from two very large dataframe which has already been loaded into memory (one of which is about 1G and the other is just over 6G).

```py
largeDF1 = pd.read_csv(directory + 'name1.csv')
largeDF2 = pd.read_csv(directory + 'name2.csv')

def f(x):
    load_content1 = largeDF1.loc[largeDF1['FirstRow'] == x]
    load_content2 = largeDF1.loc[largeDF1['FirstRow'] == x]
    #some computation happens here
    new_data.to_csv(directory + 'output.csv', index = False)

def main():
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force = True)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    input = input_data['col']
    pool.map_async(f, input)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The problem is that the files are too big and when I run them over multiple cores I get a memory issue. I want to know if there is a way where the loaded files can be shared across all processes.

I have tried manager() but could not get it to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the memory isn't shared between processes

Comment: "I have tried manager() but could not get it to work. " what did you try?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are forcing the `spawn` start method? Are you running this on ms-windows?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - What I read was that you use ` mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()` and then `ns = mgr.Namespace()` and finally `ns.df = dataframe` but I wasn't sure if you can have two dataframes there.

Comment: @RolandSmith the reason I used `spawn` was because when I didn't have that line (or had `fork`), the process starts, and then doesn't move. So for example if I had 4 cores then only 4 printouts were made (the function prints each time it's called) and then the process doesn't move forward anymore.

Comment: @Winston Are you perhaps running this from IPython? Multiprocessing and IPython don't always work well together, especially on ms-windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you were running this on a UNIX-like system (which uses the `fork` startmethod by default) the data would be shared out-of-the-box. Most operating systems use copy-on-write for memory pages. So even if you `fork` a process several times they would share most of the memory pages that contain the dataframes, al long as you don't modify those dataframes.

But when using the `spawn` start method, each worker process has to load the dataframe. I'm not sure if the OS is smart enough in that case to share the memory pages. Or indeed that these spawned processes would all have the same memory lay-out.

The only *portable* solution I can think of would be to leave the data on disk and use `mmap` in the workers to map it into memory **read-only**. That way the OS would notice that multiple processes are mapping the same file, and it would only load one copy.

The downside is that the data would be in memory in on-disk `csv` format, which makes reading data from it (without making a copy!) less convenient. So you might want to *prepare* the data beforehand into a form that it easier to use. Like e.g. convert the data from `'FirstRow'` into a binary file of `float` or `double` that you can iterate over with `struct.iter_unpack`.

The function below (from my [statusline](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/master/statusline-i3.py#L158) script) uses `mmap` to count the amount of messages in a mailbox file.

```
def mail(storage, mboxname):
    """
    Report unread mail.
    Arguments:
        storage: a dict with keys (unread, time, size) from the previous call or an empty dict.
            This dict will be *modified* by this function.
        mboxname (str): name of the mailbox to read.
    Returns: A string to display.
    """
    stats = os.stat(mboxname)
    if stats.st_size == 0:
        return 'Mail: 0'
    # When mutt modifies the mailbox, it seems to only change the
    # ctime, not the mtime! This is probably releated to how mutt saves the
    # file. See also stat(2).
    newtime = stats.st_ctime
    newsize = stats.st_size
    if not storage or newtime > storage['time'] or newsize != storage['size']:
        with open(mboxname) as mbox:
            with mmap.mmap(mbox.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ) as mm:
                start, total = 0, 1  # First mail is not found; it starts on first line...
                while True:
                    rv = mm.find(b'\n\nFrom ', start)
                    if rv == -1:
                        break
                    else:
                        total += 1
                        start = rv + 7
                start, read = 0, 0
                while True:
                    rv = mm.find(b'\nStatus: R', start)
                    if rv == -1:
                        break
                    else:
                        read += 1
                        start = rv + 10
        unread = total - read
        # Save values for the next run.
        storage['unread'], storage['time'], storage['size'] = unread, newtime, newsize
    else:
        unread = storage['unread']
    return f'Mail: {unread}'
```

*In this case* I used `mmap` because it was 4x faster than just reading the file. See [normal reading](https://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/software/attempting-a-conky-replacement-in-python-part-1.html) versus [using mmap](https://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/software/attempting-a-conky-replacement-in-python-part-2.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you be a little more specific about the use of `mmap`? I have never used this function in the past. Help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Using `mmap` basically gives you a cross between a `bytearray` and a file object. So you can `read` or `seek` like a file, or use `find` like a string.  The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) explains it very well, I think. I've added an example from my own code to my answer.